# How can I reset the VLC interface?

Tags: vlc

When I installed VLC on 12.04 beta 2 I accidentally picked the .xml file as the skin from the skins2 folder. I have purged Vlc and reinstalled but still when I start to play a video file I hear only the sound and see the screen which is a black oblong (no image) of 2cm x 4cm with which I can do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Open vlc from a terminal with `vlc -Iqt4`, then open Tools > Preferences & set back to Native or pick a skin that actually works

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because VLC still has files in your `~/.config` folder. Remove the file `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` and run `vlc` again and you should be free of issues.